# C# Raise number by 1 if folder already exist

Tags: c#, sql, .net

When I click a button it creates a new folder with the name 'new category'. When I press the button again I want it to create a folder 'new category (1)' and so on. Its the same system as when you create a new folder on your pc. This is what I have now but ofcourse this makes new category (1) over and over. Someone know how to do it to check if it exists and if so change the 1 into 2 for example. Thx!

```
        con = new SqlDbConnect();
        con.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM categorie WHERE CAT_titel=@cattitel");
        con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", "Nieuwe categorie");
        if (con.QueryEx().Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            con = new SqlDbConnect();
            con.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO categorie(CAT_titel, CAT_aanmaakdatum) VALUES(@cattitel, @catdatum)");
            con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", "Nieuwe categorie (1)");
            con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catdatum", DateTime.Now);
            con.NonQueryEx();
        }
        else
        {
            con = new SqlDbConnect();
            con.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO categorie(CAT_titel, CAT_aanmaakdatum) VALUES(@cattitel, @catdatum)");
            con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", "Nieuwe categorie");
            con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catdatum", DateTime.Now);
            con.NonQueryEx();
        }
```

Comment: What does sql have to do with folders?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: Where do you create your file? I can´t see how your code is related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all tittles that start with title you want to insert. Then loop through titles and check if name is already taken. If it is add index and check again ...

```
    con = new SqlDbConnect();
    con.SqlQuery("SELECT CAT_titel FROM categorie WHERE CAT_titel like @cattitel + '%'");
    con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", "Nieuwe categorie");
    string titel = "Nieuwe categorie";
    var res = con.QueryEx()
    if (res.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        int idx = 1;
        while(res.Select(string.Format("CAT_titel = '{0} ({1})'", titel, idx)).Length >0)
        {
            idx++;
        }
        titel = String.Format("{0} ({1})", titel, idx);
    }

    con = new SqlDbConnect();
    con.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO categorie(CAT_titel, CAT_aanmaakdatum) VALUES(@cattitel, @catdatum)");
    con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", titel);
    con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catdatum", DateTime.Now);
    con.NonQueryEx();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. With using `like` you can count existing folders.

```
con = new SqlDbConnect();
con.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM categorie WHERE CAT_titel like @cattitel + '%' ");
con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", "Nieuwe categorie");
int rc = con.QueryEx().Rows.Count;

if (rc > 0)
{
    con = new SqlDbConnect();
    con.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO categorie(CAT_titel, CAT_aanmaakdatum) VALUES(@cattitel, @catdatum)");
    con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", "Nieuwe categorie (" + (rc++).ToString() + ")");
    con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catdatum", DateTime.Now);
    con.NonQueryEx();
}
else
{
    con = new SqlDbConnect();
    con.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO categorie(CAT_titel, CAT_aanmaakdatum) VALUES(@cattitel, @catdatum)");
    con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", "Nieuwe categorie");
    con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catdatum", DateTime.Now);
    con.NonQueryEx();
}
```

Comment: Where is this different from OPs code,despite the fact that it´s open for Sql-injection?

Comment: `where` changed with `like`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the last folder and then check the folder number. To check the number you can do this:

```
resultString = Regex.Match(pasteName, @"\d+").Value;

var number = Int32.Parse(resultString);
```

`\d+` is the regex for an integer number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below :

```
con = new SqlDbConnect();
con.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM categorie WHERE CAT_titel like @cattitel");
con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", "Nieuwe categorie%");
if (con.QueryEx().Rows.Count > 0)
{
    con = new SqlDbConnect();
    con.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO categorie(CAT_titel, CAT_aanmaakdatum) VALUES(@cattitel, @catdatum)");
    con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cattitel", "Nieuwe categorie (" + con.QueryEx().Rows.Count.ToString() + ")");
    con._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catdatum", DateTime.Now);
    con.NonQueryEx();
}
```

The `Else` part is not included here as it would be same you have. If you notice the code, your query is changed to use `LIKE` operator to see if there are records already with the value `Nieuwe categorie`, If no record exists, `ELSE` will work as usual, but if it finds one record, `Nieuwe categorie (1)` will be created, if it finds two records, `Nieuwe categorie (2)` will be created and so on.